# What is the difference between using an operator overload for << and cout?

Tags: c++

I genuinely do not understand the difference. Here's a few examples:

Using the `std::cout`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void print(std::list<std::string> const &list)
{
    for (auto const &i: list)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list = { "blue", "red", "green" };

    print(list);

    return 0;
}
```

The following output is:

```
blue
red
green
```

For the 2nd example, I will be using std::cout too:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list = { "blue", "red", "green" };

    cout << list << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>’
```

So, I use the operator overload as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::list<std::string> &list)
{
    os << list << endl;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list = { "blue", "red", "green" };

    cout << list << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles just fine initially, but when I execute it, I am getting a runtime error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why can't we simply `cout` everything from the list, and why do we have to use the loop in order to print every element inside the list?

Also, how do I solve the issue of the 2nd example? I notice that when I debug my code, it is stuck inside the operator overload which I believe causes the crash.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the first example you have a proper code to print every element of the list. In the second piece of code you expect `os << list << endl;` to magically do this. But what this actually does is to call the overloaded `operator<<`, which calls itself again, which calls itself again, which calls itself again ... until your stack overflows.

Comment: I just added a new example in between the `std::cout` and operator overload in anyone is confuse why he mentioned about the 2nd piece of code being the operator overload

Comment: By default, standard containers (like `std::list`) do not have streaming operators so, if you want one, you need to provide it - hence the compilation error in your second case.   This constraint means a container can be used to hold a set of elements that do not have their own streaming operators.   Your third example is infinitely recursive (your `operator<<()` unconditionally calls itself in the statement `os << list << endl`, hence (practically) either a runtime error (due to stack exhaustion) or an infinite loop (if the compiler translates recursive calls into iteration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You insert the list into the character stream like this: `cout << list << endl;`. That calls your overload, which inserts the list into the character stream like this: `os << list << endl;`. That calls your overload, which inserts the list into the character stream, which calls your overload, which inserts the list into the character stream, which calls your overload, and so on ...

Can you spot the problem? The problem is that your function (the operator overload) calls itself recursively, unconditionally. This recursion never ends, or wouldn't ever end if it wasn't for the limited call stack that will be exhausted, which results in a *stack overflow* error.

> why do we have to use the loop

We use a loop in order to repeat the operation for each element. Repetition is what loops are for.

That said, we don't "have" to write the loop ourselves. We can alternatively call one of the standard algorithms that have written the loop for us - such as `std::for_each` or `std::copy` combined with `std::ostream_iterator` (or their `std::ranges` equivalents).

> Also, how do I solve the issue of the 2nd example?

Implement the operator overload in similar way as you implemented the `print` function, using a loop.

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::list<std::string> const &list)
{
    for (auto const &i: list)
    {
        os << i << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I kinda understand but not quite understand about the looping :')

Comment: Thank you for the answer but regarding your last solution,  Wouldnt it prints out every single element there is inside my list? What if I just want to just print a single list, for instance, the output is more or less like this: `{ "blue", "red", "green" }`

Comment: @KhalidOwlWalid What is a difference between printing every element of a single list and printing a single list? Wouldn't you want every element to be printed when you print a list?

Comment: Idk, I am still new to C++, and previously I am using python, and I have been using print to check variables, and I thought I could just simply print it like that. Hope that make sense, but fair point @eeroika

Comment: @KhalidOwlWalid The computer doesn't know what you want it to do. You have to tell it. If you want it to print a `{` you write `os << "{";` for example.

Answer (score 0):

As @eeronika mentioned, there are more ways than simply looping through the `std::list` to print its contents.

> Why can't we simply cout everything from the list

The reason for this is due to the fact that `std::list` doesn't overload `<<` for stream extraction (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

In cases such as these, you would overload `operator<<` and use the data structure's methods to create the desired output.

`std::list` spec:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list